# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" when loading an image

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing

Yes another one of those... Stack trace (meaningful part):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
```

This is happening when trying to open image files uploaded by end-users. The code is approx this (stripped down to essential parts):

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[name];
Stream stream = file.InputStream;
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
return bytes;
```

which is then used in

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
return Image.FromStream(stream);
```

So essentially it bails on trying to load image from a memory stream. This doesn't happen always. In fact I cannot reproduce the issue myself, but it happened about 20 times in the last 2 weeks to a few different users. I do not have access to the actual files that triggered the problem.

Any clues to what might be happening here would be appreciated.

Comment: It may happen if the bitmap is too large. Try making a bitmap bigger than 2000x2000 and you'll see that exception.

Comment: If it's that intermittent, are you sure users aren't uploading corrupt images?

Comment: @SteveDanner no, I am not sure. Unfortunately there is no code currently to save uploaded images before they being processed. I would have to hack on a pile of mess to add that... which I may end up doing anyway.

Comment: @YoryeNathan thanks, I will try it later today. Any idea why and how to work around that?

Comment: @IliaG I would suggest breaking up the buffer into different sections of the picture, and having a bitmap for each section. Putting those together, you can have the illusion of a complete large picture.

Comment: And you should read stream.Length bytes, not file.ContentLength bytes.

Comment: @YoryeNathan `ContentLength` returns exactly that. Can you please clarify your previous comment? How would I go about that?

Comment: @IliaG I find it more logical to read the length of the stream, but that's my own preference. Regarding your question about the stream breaking - does the stream contain only image-bytes or other bitmap information as well? What format is the stream?

Comment: @YoryeNathan It is whatever is sent from `<input type=file />`. So it is an image file, which can be in any of the standard formats (JPG, PNG, etc.)

Comment: Well, you must have some standard type, or at least save the file type someplace, so you know how to read the files.

Comment: @YoryeNathan btw I tried uploading a jpeg file that is way bigger than 2000x2000 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you link to a pastebin with the bytes of your stream, so we can test stuff ourselves and come back with a certain answer?

Answer (score 3):

`stream.Read(bytes, 0, file.ContentLength);` doesn't mean it will read exactly `file.ContentLength` bytes. Read bytes may be less.   You should check the returned value. You may need a loop there.

[Stream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx)

Comment: Instead of a loop, you could use `Stream.CopyTo( file.InputStream, memory_stream )` [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx)

Comment: Good point for a general case, but I am not convinced it makes any difference here. I will try it regardless and see if it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make your read look someting like this:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[name]; 
Stream stream = file.InputStream; 
byte[] bytes = new byte[ContentLength];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, ContentLength);
int offset = bytesRead;
while(bytesRead > 0)
{
     bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, offset, ContentLength - offset);
     offset += bytesRead;
} 
return bytes;
```